# Find the rectangular equation and orientation of the curve

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates, parametric

The given parametric equations are
$$x=t^2-2$$
$$y=5-2t$$
solving the $x$ equation I get $t=\pm\sqrt{x+2}$ then plugging that value into the $y$ equation gives me $$y=5-2\sqrt{x+2}$$ from this I can sketch the curve with is orientated counter-clockwise to the right.
When I checked my answer the final equation should be $(y-5)^2=4x+8$. So am I meant to manipulate the equation I have now to get that or is it something else?

Comment: Wouldn’t it have been simpler to solve the second equation for $t$ and then substitute into the first instead of the other way around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$t$ should be $\pm \sqrt{x+1}$ and the final answer should be $y = 5\pm 2\sqrt{x+1} $

which is the same way of saying ${(y-5})^2 = 4x+4$

This mistake you have done is, you have only included the negative solution of $t$ so you only get 1 part of the curve, when you include the other part as well(the + solution) you will get the complete curve.

I hope this helps.

Comment: In case you want to see the graph :https://www.desmos.com/calculator/uhqirershf

Comment: So the solution is wrong or the $x$-equation should be $x=t^2-2$